# Django - Restrict Stripe SuccessUrl access

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have just integrated Stripe Checkout with my Django app. However, from their code:

```
 session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        customer_email=customer.email,
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=line_items,

        mode='payment',
        success_url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/SUCCESS/?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart'
        )
```

It redirects to a Success_url. I would like to display their order info and send an email from the success page but currently, everyone can visit(would cause random emails etc). Is there a way i can limit this for the person that just checked out? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success page should really just be a page to let your users know that their payment went through. I wouldn't personally recommend triggering any app-specific logic when your users land on it. As you've pointed out this could cause accidents with users randomly stumbling on that page and triggering emails. It also offers an opportunity for bad actors to exploit your application.

Instead, I would create a [webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build) and listen for the [checkout.session.completed](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) event, and trigger your emails from there. Building a webhook endpoint should be no more difficult than building any other endpoint on your server, with there only being some small extra logic to [verify incoming requests](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures).

Another option would be to use a tool like Zapier to listen for these events from Stripe and trigger various flows from them: https://stripe.com/partners/zapier

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Trying out the webhook with their CLI (as i am using locahost atm) and can only seem to receive 4xx Errors. urls set to  path('webhook/', store_views.receive_webhook). Cli set to: http://localhost:8000/webhook/
Any obvious flaws?